# Google fonts treated as insecure script in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, secure-coding

When I am using Google Fonts in an HTTPS page but it is treated like an "unsafe script" in chrome.

IS there any way around this issue?

I am getting this:

http://snag.gy/9FAx3.jpg

And I am using `@import` to import it.

Comment: Are you using `https://` when loading the Google Fonts? If so, could you post the exact error message you're seeing in Chrome? And show us the URL/method you're using to retrieve the Google Fonts.

Comment: Thanks. Can you include the whole `@import` line? I was suspecting the same as @edwardm's answer – that you may be loading it as `http://` instead of `https://` (or `//`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `https` or simply leave the protocol off in the `href`. For example:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```